# Pre-training accuracy calculation gives ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I am trying to model a LSTM model using the following code:

```
X_train,X_valtest,Y_train,Y_valtest = train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=37)
X_val,X_test,Y_val,Y_test = train_test_split(X_valtest,Y_valtest,test_size=0.5,random_state=37)
  
print(X_train.shape,X_val.shape,X_test.shape,Y_train.shape,Y_val.shape,Y_test.shape)
#(219, 100, 32) (27, 100, 32) (28, 100, 32) (219, 5) (27, 5) (28, 5)

#LSTM architecture

num_rows = X_train.shape[1]
num_columns = X_train.shape[2]
num_channels = 1

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], num_rows, num_columns, num_channels)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], num_rows, num_columns, num_channels)

print("after reshaping:", X_train.shape, X_test.shape)
#(219, 100, 32, 1) (28, 100, 32, 1)

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True, input_shape = (num_columns,num_rows)))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
print("Shape after the first layer:", model.output.shape)

model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
print("Shape after the second layer:", model.output.shape)

model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
print("Shape after the third layer:", model.output.shape)

model.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences = False))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
print("Shape after the fourth layer:", model.output.shape)

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(units = 31))  # units = 31 because the number of classes is 31
print("Shape after the last layer:", model.output.shape)

# Compile the model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

# Display model architecture summary 
model.summary()


# Calculate pre-training accuracy 
score = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=1)
accuracy = 100*score[1]
```

I am able to get the model summary but I am not able to calculate the value of score/pre-training accuracy. It gives me an error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_22 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 100, 32, 1)

What is that I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the model expects an input that is 2 dimensional, where your is 3 dimensional... you can see it with:

```
print(X_test.shape) # you will get something like (X,Y,Z,1)
```

pretty sure that the last dim is useless in your case, so probably what you want is this:

```
score = model.evaluate(X_test.squeeze(), Y_test, verbose=1)
```

Comment: Yes, the X_test.shape is (28, 100, 32, 1). When I used the squeeze(), it gives me this error: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential_23: expected shape=(None, None, 100), found shape=(None, 100, 32)